# How to Refresh center panel and refresh the content

Tags: javascript, extjs, controller, extjs6

I have a border layout in which west side have few buttons. On click of buttons few `panels` will show in central panel. Here is example code of the one panel which display in central panel.

```
{
        xtype: 'myPanel', //  User define panel
        itemId: 'myPanel1',
        showZoom: false,
        showLegends:false,
        showSlider: false,
        showDataGrid: true,
        chartType: 'line',
        controlPanel:false,
        orientation: 'x'
    }
```

Now I have one buton called `setting` which open one window. Window having some `checkboxes`. In that I have one `checkbox` called Zoom. I want when I click on checkbox zoom then from above panel `showZoom : true`. Right now showzoom is false but on check it should be true and refresh the panel and display the result accordingly.

> **Controller code for Zoom**

```
onzoomPanelClick: function(field, checked) {
    var me = this;
    var centerContainer = Ext.getCmp('center');
    var graphIDItem = centerContainer.items.items;
    if (checked) {
        for (var i = 0; i < graphIDItem.length; i++) {
            if (graphIDItem[i].chartType == "line") {
                graphIDItem[i].showZoom = true;
            } else if (graphIDItem[i].chartType == "groupedBoxPlot") {
                graphIDItem[i].showZoom = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < graphIDItem.length; i++){
            graphIDItem[i].showZoom = false;
        }
    }
}
```

How to make `showZoom : true` on click of check box and show the result in center pan. I tried with refresh but did'nt work.

> showZoom

```
 if (me.showZoom) {
 graphConfig.graphPanel.itemId = graphConfig.itemId + 'ZoomPanel';
 zPanel = Ext.create('mgo.panel.ZoomPanel', graphConfig.graphPanel);
 cPanel.add(zPanel);
```

}

```
 if (this.config.showZoom) {
 mgoCenterPanelItems.push(Ext.create('mgo.panel.ZoomPanel',     this.config.graphPanel));
```

}

Comment: Where did you get `showZoom` from? AFAIK it's not a chart config option.